# Recyclerview scrolls automatically when loading images from network

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fresco

I am developing a chat app, and when I open a chat with images (that I am loading using Fresco), it scrolls automatically. Initially, I was using Picasso for loading image, but I tried changing it with other libraries, but the issue remained same. Can anyone guide me what could be the issue or what is the right direction to fix the issue?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to Fresco? Just try to remove image inflating (don't set image url) and if you have the same issue.

Comment: I also was working and chat implementation and used Fresco. I never faced this issue

Comment: no this is not related to fresco

Comment: @zohad check in your code where you call `scrollToPosition`

Comment: here is the full adapter code https://gist.github.com/khaliqzohaib92/a5a27243087aa307d725e4d41d83990d

Comment: Not in adapter, Do you interact with Layout manager to scroll?

Comment: no i am using this to scroll                             recyclerView_messenger_messages.scrollToPosition(messengerAdapter.getItemCount()-1);

Comment: When you do you call it?

Comment: every thing was working fine. Until i added the attachment support for images in the app.

Comment: after adding all the images in the reyclerview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181634/discussion-between-zohaib-khaliq-and-igor-bykov).

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Delayed the call to scrollToPosition until recycler view item gets loaded.

Comment: This looks like a workaround. List cells shouldn't resize once an image is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this call

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(yourListMessages.size() - 1);
```

It will set to bottom of your list of messages

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this issue, either use image placeholders while an image is loading or establish a minimum size for your cell that's close to the size of the image once it's loaded. It looks your cell is re-sized to fit the image when loading is done, causing rest of the content in your recycler view to shift to accommodate new cell size.

Another thing to try is to set a defined height on your `ImageView` and use any of the options from `android:scaleType` to match how you display an image in your cell based on your needs.

Comment: Image size may vary sir.

Comment: Well now that you know what the issue is, I am sure you will find a way to deal with it. I have no idea of your business requirements to suggest any more solutions.

Comment: @zohaibkhaliq If any of these answers helped you, you should upvote/accept it.

Comment: The one how commented on the question helped me.

Comment: @zohaibkhaliq You should post the solution you found as a separate answer if it's different from any of the answers here. This way people who have the same issues will be able to resolve them,